# Having problems switching nodes in a linked list java

Tags: java, linked-list, logic

I am attempting to switch two nodes in a linked list in java and am having some issues. My sorting algorithm works properly as I checked it by switching the contents of the node, but when attempting to switch the nodes themselves I am getting issues.

The following is my node switch code:

```
                Node tmp = current;
                tmp.next = current.next.next;

                Node tmp2 = current.next;
                tmp2.next = current;


                current.next = tmp;
                current = tmp2;
```

With this code however, my loop keeps looping so I am sure there is a problem with my switching logic. If anyone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it.

** to clarify: I am aiming to switch current and current.next.

Thank you!

Comment: which two nodes are you aiming to switch?

Comment: I am aiming to switch current and current.next

Comment: When I did this back in college I made sure I grabbed the `node` before the first `node` that I wanted to swap. At this point it's just linking the next 3 `nodes` correctly.

Comment: When you set `tmp.next = current.next.next` you are also setting `current.next = current.next.next` because `tmp` is also referencing `current`.  This means you have lost your reference to `current.next`.

Comment: What do you think these two lines do: `Node tmp = current; current.next = tmp`? Where does `current.next` point after these lines are executed?

Comment: @dima I assumed that tmp would copy the current node, and then that current.next (which is also a node) would copy the node at current

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Back when I did this in college, in order to swap 2 nodes you want to grab the node that's before the first node you wish to swap. For instance. If you have

`----> currNode -> node_A -> node_B -> node_C ------>`

Here we wish to swap `node_A` with `node_B` so we stop at `currNode` since we need to set `currNode.next` to `node_B`.

Following this, we have the following (i'm assuming it'll get passed into some method):

```
Node tmp = curr;
Node A = curr.next;
Node B = curr.next.next;
Node C = curr.next.next.next;
```

Now we just need to set the right things.

```
tmp.setNext(B);  //Now we have ----> tmp -> B
B.setNext(A);   //Now we have  ----> tmp -> B -> A
A.setNext(C);   //Now we have ----> tmp -> B -> A -> C --->
```

Now if `node_A` happens to be the first node or if `node_B` happens to be the last node then there's gotta be some extra conditions in there you might want to keep in mind.

You can tell if `node_A` happens to be the first node in your linked list, You can have some for of check like:

```
public void swap (NodeStructure nodeStructure, Node Node_A, Node Node_B){
    Node A = Node_A;
    Node B = Node_b;
    if(nodeStructure.head == A){
       //Node A is the first Node, so we need to handle it in a special way.
       Node tmp = Node_A;
       nodeStructure.setHead(B); //Now we have -> B
       B.setNext(tmp);           //Now we have -> B -> A
       A.setNext(C);             //Now we have -> B -> A -> C ------>
    }

    //or in the case of the tail 

    if(nodeStructure.tail == B){
       //Node B is the last Node, in this case, we don't need node_C
       /*Iterate through nodeStructure until you reach node before A and  
         assign this to tmp.*/
       nodeStructure.setTail(A); //Let's set the tail first
       tmp.setNext(B);  //Now we have ----> tmp -> B
       B.setNext(A);   //Now we have  ----> tmp -> B -> A
    }

     /* Depeding on how you decide to implement, you might also have a third 
        condition checking if Node_A is the head and Node_B is tail.*/

    //Handle condition where there's no special cases.
}
```

Comment: at some point the node c = curr.next.next.next line throws a null pointer exception for some reason so its not working

Comment: @user3105072, You have to keep in mind that there'll be special conditions if the nodes you are trying to swap are the first and/or last. if that is throwing an exception it means that node_B is the last node. At which point you don't need node_C.

Comment: im still having problems putting it all together.. could you edit your answer with how the code I could plug in to change current and current.next?

Comment: @user3105072 do you keep track of the head and tail of the node structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
Node tmp = current;
tmp.next = current.next.next;
```

The code above first gets the current node and makes `tmp` point to it. Then it changes the next of `tmp`. The problem is, that also will change `current`, since they point to the same thing.

You want something like:

```
Node tmp = current.next.next;
current.next.next = current;
current.next = tmp;
```

Comment: for some reason when I tried your suggestion I lost about half my nodes. Where do you set current?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.  I'm using slightly different naming conventions to you but the code is swapping the nodes at `current` and `current.next`.

```
Node head = current.next; // the node to become the start of the list (may be null)

if (head != null) {
  // swap current node's position
  current.next = head.next;
  head.next = current;

  // update the node current is pointing to
  current = head;
}
```

Visually this is what's happening:

`Current -> B -> Rest of List...` will become `B -> Current -> Rest of List...`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally figured it out!

I was going at it all wrong.It was simply a problem of re-linking. The following was my solution:

```
                Node temp = current;
                Node prevNext = prev.next;
                Node currentNext = current.next;
                Node currentNextNext = current.next.next;


                current.next.next = temp;
                current.next = currentNextNext;
                prev.next = currentNext;
```

Hope it helps anyone who might be stuck like I was!